# Detectar AdBlock e exibir uma mensagem

Tags: javascript

O que eu estou tentando fazer é detectar ***Adblock Plus*** e exibir uma mensagem.

Comment: Eu vou inventar uma coisa para detectar detectores de adblock e desabilitar, pois isso está tirando o direito de usuário de não querer ver certas propagandas.

Comment: Próxima pergunta do site: "Como detectar e bloquear detector de detector de AdBlock"?

Comment: @Bacco já tem o [Anti AdBlock Killer](https://github.com/reek/anti-adblock-killer). Estou usando com TamperMonkey, e funciona mesmo!

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Tou falando de um pra detectar isso aí e bloquear :)

Comment: Sei que a pergunta é antiga, mas me espanta ver respostas que não acrescentam nada vindas de usuários com reputação alta. O autor pode ter razões para exibir uma mensagem aos que bloqueiam anúncio que não sejam "tirar direito do usuário de não querer ver anúncios".

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Existe um plugin pra isto chamado [BlockAdBlock](https://github.com/sitexw/BlockAdBlock) (ou <s>[FuckAdBlock](https://github.com/sitexw/FuckAdBlock)</s>), ele é suportado pelos seguintes navegadores:

- Google Chrome
- Mozilla Firefox
- Internet Explorer (8+)
- Safari
- Opera

### Instalação

Você pode instalar manualmente baixando em https://github.com/sitexw/BlockAdBlock/releases ou:

- **Bower:**

  ```
  bower install blockadblock
  ```
- **Node.js/io.js:**

  ```
  npm install blockadblock
  ```

### Exemplo de uso:

```
<script src="blockAdBlock.js"></script>
<script>
(function() {
    //Se não detectar o adblock
    function adBlockNotDetected() {
        alert('AdBlock não está ativado');
    }

    //Se detectar o adblock
    function adBlockDetected() {
        alert('AdBlock está ativado');
    }

    if(typeof blockAdBlock=== 'undefined') {
        alert("blockAdBlock não foi carregado");
    } else {
        blockAdBlock.onDetected(adBlockDetected);
        blockAdBlock.onNotDetected(adBlockNotDetected);
        blockAdBlock.on(true, adBlockDetected);
        blockAdBlock.on(false, adBlockNotDetected);
        blockAdBlock.on(true, adBlockDetected).onNotDetected(adBlockNotDetected);
    }

    blockAdBlock.setOption('checkOnLoad', false);

    blockAdBlock.setOption({
        debug: true,
        checkOnLoad: false,
        resetOnEnd: false
    });
})();
</script>
```

### Alternativa

Todavia nem tudo é garantido, os adblocks evoluem e isso pode dificultar, uma coisa simples que pode fazer é usar o evento `onerror`

```
<script>
function possivelAdblockDetectado () {
    alert("Possível adblock detectado");
}
</script>

<script onerror="possivelAdblockDetectado()" async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
    style="display:inline-block;width:300px;height:250px"
    data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    data-ad-slot="6440411535"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

Ou então usar `window.addEventListener` (não funciona com `window.onerror`)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function () {
    var
        removeProtocol = /^[a-z]+[:]/i,
        items = [
            "//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js",
            "//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"
        ];

    function detectAdBlock(src) {
        if (items.indexOf(src.replace(removeProtocol, "")) !== -1) {
            alert("Possivel adblock");
        }
    }

    window.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
        if (e.target && e.target.src) {
            detectAdBlock(e.target.src);
        }
    }, true);
})();
</script>
```

Comment: Mas ele chega a bloquear mesmo, como o nome diz, ou só exibe msg mesmo?

Comment: Você configura a função `function adBlockNotDetected() {
        alert('AdBlock não está ativado');
    }
` como quiser, basta trocar o `alert`, pode colocar um modal bootstrap, ou redirecionar para outra página. Vai da sua imaginação e imaginação não tem limites :)

Comment: Show, Obrigado, rsrsr.