# Anti-adblock que substitui div

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, plugin, plugin-wordpress

Preciso de um plugin para wordpress ou script no qual aprece uma mensagem para o usuário que tem adblock.

Contudo, quero que essa mensagem apareça no lugar de uma div.

Já tentei os Plugins:

**JGC AdBlocker Detector** - Esse não aceita estilo (mostra o estilo como se fosse um texto simples)

**Ad Blocker Notify Lite** - Esse funciona no servidor local, mas não funciona no servidor online.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar o [BlockAdBlock](https://github.com/sitexw/BlockAdBlock) (ou <s>[FuckAdBlock](https://github.com/sitexw/FuckAdBlock)</s>)

como respondi em: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/87992/3635

Se tiver jQuery (geralmente wordpress usa) pode fazer assim:

```
<script src="blockAdBlock.js"></script>
<script>
(function() {
    function adBlockDetected() {
        $(function () {
            $('#div_especifica').text("adblock detectado");
        });
    }

    function adBlockNotDetected() {
        console.log("Sem adblock");
    }

    if(typeof blockAdBlock=== 'undefined') {
        alert("blockAdBlock não foi carregado");
    } else {
        blockAdBlock.onDetected(adBlockDetected);
        blockAdBlock.onNotDetected(adBlockNotDetected);
        blockAdBlock.on(true, adBlockDetected);
        blockAdBlock.on(false, adBlockNotDetected);
        blockAdBlock.on(true, adBlockDetected).onNotDetected(adBlockNotDetected);
    }

    blockAdBlock.setOption('checkOnLoad', false);

    blockAdBlock.setOption({
        debug: true,
        checkOnLoad: false,
        resetOnEnd: false
    });
})();
</script>
```

Supondo que o elemento seja algo como:

```
 <div id="div_especifica"></div>
```

---

### Alternativa

Se estiver usando googleanalitycs poderia usar assim:

```
<script>
function possivelAdblockDetectado () {
    $(function () {
        $('#div_especifica').text("adblock detectado");
    });
}
</script>

<script onerror="possivelAdblockDetectado()" async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
    style="display:inline-block;width:300px;height:250px"
    data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    data-ad-slot="6440411535"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

Comment: Não sei se fiz errado, mas eu tentei colocar pra substituir uma classe, mas mesmo com adblock ligado aparecer, "blockAdBlock não foi carregado".

Comment: @Marcio.sx você adicionou o `<script src="blockAdBlock.js"></script>` no `<head>`? Sabe que tem que colocar o blockAdblock.js dentro do seu site né?

Comment: O arquivo blockAdBlock.js deve ser chamado né?! XD 
Nem tinha feito isso

Comment: Eu chamei o blockAdBlock.js, mas agora não apareceu nada! Deveria aparecer "adblock detectado" no lugar da div né?

Comment: @Marcio.sx olha no console do navegador se não tem nenhum erro.

Comment: Sem erro, olha  o que aparece:[BlockAdBlock][setOption] The option "debug" he was assigned to "true"
blockAdBlock.js:57 [BlockAdBlock][setOption] The option "checkOnLoad" he was assigned to "false"
blockAdBlock.js:57 [BlockAdBlock][setOption] The option "resetOnEnd" he was assigned to "false"

Comment: @Marcio.sx editei a resposta, tenta agora

Comment: Mudei da forma que mandou e ainda assim nada!

Comment: @Marcio.sx coloca um `alert` dentro do `possivelAdblockDetectado`, assim `function possivelAdblockDetectado () { alert('testando'); }`, se aparecer um alert no teu site é porque o problema não é o BlockAdblock.

Comment: Não deu o alert, fiz assim: function adBlockDetected() {
        function possivelAdblockDetectado () { alert('testando'); }
    }

Comment: Esse código ainda nunca vai executar e não esta igual ao que eu postei @Marcio.sx, por favor faça exatamente como eu fiz na resposta.

Comment: Você já me ajudou de mais cara, obrigado! Eu não entendo muito de js, então vou chamar meu amigo ele vai entender sua resposta.
Sou eternamente grato! :-)

Comment: @Marcio.sx Faz assim, muda pra isto somente:  `function adBlockDetected() { alert('testando'); }`

Answer (score 2):

Existem várias formas de detectar o bloqueios de anúncio, porém nenhuma é 100% garantida, testei um `script` retirado de uma resposta do @Guilherme Nascimento: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/87992/3635

```
<script>
    function possivelAdblockDetectado () {       
        document.getElementById("id-div").innerHTML = "Conteúdo html que você quer mostrar no lugar";
}
</script>

<script onerror="possivelAdblockDetectado()" async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
```

Esse `script` tenta carregar o ADS do Google, se não for possível, devido ao bloqueio de anúncio (ou qualquer outro motivo), ele vai chamar una função `possivelAdblockDetectado ()`, e nela você pode trocar o conteúdo da `div` que você quiser.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Nossa sua resposta parece exatamente com o meu código https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/293984/3635 - supondo que você tenha copiado parte dele seria muito legal se você creditasse né? Afinal de contas sair copiando código alheio dos outros sem citar a fonte é desmerecer bastante o esforço dos colegas, não concorda? Até mesmo o nome da função `possivelAdblockDetectado` é igual :/

Comment: Não lembro se foi da sua resposta, provavelmente sim, mas não dessa aí do comentário, a de 2015, uso esse script a algum tempo já, pra essa resposta peguei do meu código msm, de qq forma adicionei os créditos, desculpa qq coisa.

Comment: Copie o link errado, era para ser o de 2015, obrigado por creditar!